# Why images are not loading in Phaser?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I am following this [tutorial](https://phaser.io/tutorials/making-your-first-phaser-3-game/part1)
And I did everything as told, but my images don't load, and I get this: [image]

**My code:**

main.js:

```
/** @type{import{"../libs/phaser"}} */


var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO, 
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    scene: {
        preload: preload,
        create: create,
        update: update
    }
};

function preload ()
{
    this.load.image('sky', 'assets/sky.png');
    this.load.image('ground', 'assets/platform.png');
    this.load.image('star', 'assets/star.png');
    this.load.image('bomb', 'assets/bomb.png');
    this.load.spritesheet('dude', 
        'assets/dude.png',
        { frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 48 }
    );
}

function create ()
{
    this.add.image(400, 300, 'sky'); 
    this.add.image(400, 300, 'star');
}

function update ()
{
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
game.state.add('GameState',GameState);
game.state.start('GameState')
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./libs/phaser.js"></script>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My project structure:**

[image]

**Thing I tried:**

1. Running on chrome/edge/firefox
2. Moving .png outside the folder

I suppose it is not a problem with a code, so I don't know where it is and how to solve it.
This is my error:

[image]

Comment: You need to actually serve that content. You are double clicking the HTML file and should have `file:///...` in your address bar, which prevents phaser from loading the assets. You can install Apache, or Python or node to use your own computer as web server. It's explained here: https://phaser.io/tutorials/getting-started-phaser3 (specifically under "A web server? But I want to make games!") (also, you need to definitely learn how to use the browser's dev tools, specifically the console. Press F12 to open them and check the console tab, and you should see a nice red CORS error for each asset)

Comment: @ChrisG I am using node, and I am running it on server

Comment: Ok, so check the browser console. Turn on XHRs and refresh the page. You should see phaser loading the assets, including what goes wrong.

Comment: @ChrisG I edited my question, and added ss of error. I still don't know how to fix it

Comment: How are you starting the server? It looks like some webpack is going on.

Comment: Please include main.js

Answer (score 0):

Put `./` in front of assets. Eg.

```
this.load.image('ground', './assets/platform.png');
```

Cheers